# Paley-Zygmund-like inequality

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Let ${X}$ be a non-negative random variable that is almost surely bounded but not identically zero, show that

$\displaystyle \mathop{\bf P}( X \geq \frac{1}{2} \mathop{\bf E} X) \geq \frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathop{\bf E} X}{\|X\|_\infty}$.

By Paley-Zygmund inequality LHS $\geq \frac{1}{4} \frac{({\bf E}X)^2}{{\bf E}(|X|^2)}$. Are we expected to show that this term is larger than RHS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mu = EX$ You can prove the inequality in a similar way to how Payley zygmund is proved. Since
$$
X = XI(X<\mu/2) + XI(X\ge \mu/2)\leq \mu/2 + {\|X\|_\infty}I(X\geq \mu/2)
$$
where $I$ is the indicator function. Take expectations of both sides to deduce that
$$
\mu\leq\mu/2+{\|X\|_\infty}P(X\geq \mu/2)
$$
and rearranging yields the reuslt.